# mySQL adding duplicate data to TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx

I want to add data from mySql database to a table view using observable list as well, using a "Refresh button" that adds new rows to the tableview everytime it is clicked. Here is the code:

```
 public void refreshPage(){

    Order curOrder = ordersList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    ordersList.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    String query = "SELECT orderID, orderStatus, orderTotalCost FROM ORDERS";
    try {

        DatabaseConnection DBconn = new DatabaseConnection();
        connection = DBconn.getDatabaseLink();
        //  connection = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (resultSet.next()){
                    Order newOrder = new Order(resultSet.getString("orderID"), resultSet.getString("orderStatus"), resultSet.getDouble("orderTotalCost"));
                    orders.add(newOrder);
        }

        ordersList.setItems(orders);



    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

refreshPage() is linked to a button on the javaFX stage.
ordersList is the tableView and orders is the observable list.

However, the issue is that when clicking the refresh page button multiple times, it adds the same rows from the data base over and over, I only want it to add unique values to the tableview from the database.

Comment: [mcve] please .. mock the db connection with hard-coded data (after being certain that the db access returns values as expected :)

Comment: .. and stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: I did mock db connection and it worked, I want it to not add the same data when I click the button again

Comment: That just sounds like you have duplicate items in your database...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ObservableSet** to avoid adding duplicated items.
Create set:

```
ObservableSet<Order> observableSet = FXCollections.observableSet();
```

Add new items to set (duplicates will be skipped):

```
observableSet.add(newOrder);
```